# "Missing argument"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm a PHP noob and have a question which seems to be simply - not as said, I'm a noob and can't solve it myself.

I have a wordpress blog running a template, and when searching without any searchresults, a error shows in the top of the page:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_page_id(), called in /var/www/titanen.dk/public_html/spillersmart/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/functions.php on line 262 and defined in /var/www/titanen.dk/public_html/spillersmart/wp-content/themes/WPTube4/functions.php on line 237
```

The functions.php can be seen here http://spillersmart.dk/functions.txt and a example of the page can be seen here http://spillersmart.dk/?s=xxx

Thanks in advance, guys! :-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem sounds like it is somewhere within the theme, what the error means is: At line 262 inside functions.php this is happening.

```
function tube_getcustomfield($filedname, $page_current_id = NULL)
{
    if($page_current_id==NULL)
        $page_current_id = get_page_id();    //!HERE IS THE PROBLEM!

    $value = get_post_meta($page_current_id, $filedname, true);

    return $value;
}
```

The function get_page_id(); is being called without supplying an argument, and if you look at the definition for the function:

```
function get_page_id($page_name){
    global $wpdb;
    $page_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name =    '".$page_name."' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page'");
    return $page_name;
}
```

This function requires one argument. Without getting a better look at how the theme has been built I don't know exactly how the get_page_id() function is being used. I wonder whether that line of code should be changed to

```
    $page_current_id = get_page_id($filedname);
```

If this doesn't work then see if you can get a more up to date version of the theme you are using.

Comment: There isn't any newer versions of the theme, i'm afraid. :(